# Make a json array with elements name and value and give it to php with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I want to take all elements from each 2 rows if a checkbox is chekced and make them in a json array and send it with ajax to the php.

```
$('input.pay').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id').split('_');
        type = row[0];
        payID= row[1];
        payJsonArr = '';
        secondRow=', #'+type+'_'+payID+$('#rate_'+payID).attr('class');

        $('#'+type+'_'+payID+secondRow).find('.take').each(function(){
            if($(this).is('input') || $(this).is('select'))
                payJsonArr += $(this).attr('name') + ':' + $(this).val()+',';   
            else if($(this).is('td') || $(this).is('span'))
                payJsonArr += $(this).attr('name') +':'+ $(this).html().trim()+',';
        });
        payJsonArr += payJsonArr.substring(0, payJsonArr.length - 1);
        payments[payID]= '{'+payJsonArr+'}';
    }
});
```

The problem is that with that code i get the array in php i get the fallowing:

```
array(1) {
  [791]=>
  string(501) "{field 1:2012-10-07,field 2:6777.00 }"
}
```

How can i get it like it should if it was a JSON,like that :

```
array(1) {
  [791]=>
    [field 1]=>'2012-10-07',
    [field 2]=>'6777.00'
}
```

If anybody can help i would appreciate it.Thank you all for helping those in need.

Comment: there's no such thing as a "json array". There's json strings, which contain textual representations of a javascript data structure. You don't "build a json array". You build a JS data structure, then convert it to json as the very last step before sending that json string somewhere else. It would appear that you're double-encoding: building your own (invalid/broken) json string, which jquery than re-json-encodes.

Comment: the json is invalid due to lack of quotes

Comment: Actually everything can be interpreted as an array.Aspecially a string.Like $string = 'abc' and you can get 'c' like that $string[2].Thank you for your pointless  clarification.I am fully aware of what JSON is.Just the last part would have done the job :"the json is invalid due to lack of quotes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what Rohit suggested, try this (this is untested):

```
$('input.pay').each(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
    row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id').split('_');
    type = row[0];
    payID= row[1];
    payJsonArr = {};
    secondRow=', #'+type+'_'+payID+$('#rate_'+payID).attr('class');

    $('#'+type+'_'+payID+secondRow).find('.take').each(function(){
        if($(this).is('input') || $(this).is('select'))
            payJsonArr[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();   
        else if($(this).is('td') || $(this).is('span'))
            payJsonArr[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).html().trim();
    });
    payments[payID]= payJsonArr;
}
```

});

Comment: Lol,should have looked at your post earlier :) defining the arrays like object {} is exactly what was missing from the post above.Thanks you all.You helped me alot :)

Comment: @LachezarRaychev No prob. If this is what you needed, please mark this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use like that,

```
    `var payJsonArr = [];
    $('#'+type+'_'+payID+secondRow).find('.take').each(function(){
        if($(this).is('input') || $(this).is('select'))
            payJsonArr[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();   
        else if($(this).is('td') || $(this).is('span'))
            payJsonArr[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).html().trim(); 
    });

    payments[payID]= payJsonArr;`
```

If you want to learn more about JSON then you can see 
some nice examples here : [JSON](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.in/p/json.html)

Comment: This worked exactly how i wanted with 2 small fixes.It doesn't work if var payments = []; and var payJsonArr = [];It works though if you define them like obejcts: var payemnets = {};var payJsonArr={}; Thank you for the great tip.I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to create a string which can be converted into JSON. For this create the string eg:

```
var jsonString= {
             "field1":"value",
             "field2":"value" 

           };
```

Always keep in mind if you are using double quotes and then use only double quotes and if using single quote then always use single quote.